# Access sportsreference.nhl Abstract Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, python-import

I am having a hard time pulling data from an abstract class associated with an API.I am looking to pull player stats for an individual game using 'sportsreference' API. You need access  `sportsreference.nhl.boxscore.BoxscorePlayer` abstract class to pull this information. Here is the API documentation https://sportsreference.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nhl.html#schedule

Code:

```
from sportsreference.nhl.boxscore.BoxscorePlayer import BoxscorePlayer
from sportsreference.nhl.boxscore import Boxscores
```

..
..
..

for game in team_schedule:

```
game_date = datetime.strptime(game.date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
if game_date <= today :

    print(game_date)
    print(game.result)
    df = game.boxscore.dataframe
    r = game.boxscore.BoxscorePlayer('Timo Meier').dataframe
    print(r)
```

&

```
from sportsreference.nhl.boxscore import Boxscores, BoxscorePlayer
```

for game in team_schedule:

```
game_date = datetime.strptime(game.date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
if game_date <= today :

    print(game_date)
    print(game.result)
    df = game.boxscore.dataframe
    r = game.boxscore('Timo Meier').dataframe
    print(r)
```

Error Log:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'sportsreference.nhl.boxscore.BoxscorePlayer';
>   'sportsreference.nhl.boxscore' is not a package

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access game level player data this way.

```
from sportsreference.nhl.boxscore import Boxscores, BoxscorePlayer
from sportsreference.nhl.teams import Teams
from sportsreference.nhl.schedule import Schedule
from sportsreference.nhl.roster import Player
from sportsreference.nhl.roster import Roster
from time import gmtime
from datetime import datetim

sharks_schedule = Schedule('SJS')

for game in sharks_schedule:
   boxscore = game.boxscore
   q = boxscore.home_players
   e = boxscore.away_players
   for player in q:
      r = player.dataframe
      print(r.goals)
```